# TCL Expect Using Regular Expressions to Extract String

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I'm trying to extract strings from a file that match the following format:

AP[1st nibble].[2nd nibble].[3rd nibble]

For example:  AP30f7.0df6.e51c

The code below captures all data sharing the same line as the above string.  What can I do to stop capturing any undesired data found on the same line as the above string?

```
while { [gets $fchan inline] >= 0} {
    switch -regexp -- $inline {
        AP([a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}) {
            append default_name $inline\n
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Found a work around.  Since each line matching the condition I've specified starts with the desired string, I'll use the *string range* command to extract only the first 16 characters.

```
while { [gets $fchan inline] >= 0} {
    switch -regexp -- $inline {
        AP([a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}) {
            set inline_mod [string range $inline 0 15]
            append default_name $inline_mod\n
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `switch` command has some useful options when you want to do extraction at the same time as matching an RE. In particular, you should use [the `-matchvar` option](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/switch.htm#M9).

```
while { [gets $fchan inline] >= 0} {
    switch -regexp -matchvar matched -- $inline {
        AP([a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}) {
            # Extract the first and second elements
            lassign $matched inline_mod triple
            # With your sample of AP30f7.0df6.e51c
            #   $inline_mod is "AP30f7.0df6.e51c"
            #   $triple is "30f7.0df6.e51c"
            append default_name $inline_mod\n
        }
    }
}
```

There are some further examples on that manual page.